# woocommerce, allow to take product twice respecting the quantity limitation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need some help with a WooCommerce issue.

For instance, I want to set min for the product "Product A" at 1, the maximum at 3 and if the customer wants more he can add several "Product A" but with the same quantity control.

Actually, I've added the following code to functions.php file:

```
function namespace_force_individual_cart_items( $cart_item_data, $product_id ) {
  $unique_cart_item_key = md5( microtime() . rand() );
  $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = $unique_cart_item_key;

  return $cart_item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'namespace_force_individual_cart_items', 10, 2 );
```

It allows me to add same product to cart twice instead of changing quantity in WooCommerce.

It works fine but when I enable the plugin for min max quantity control the previous behavior not work anymore.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're running into an issue with the Min/Max Quantities plugin that doesn't allow the custom function you've added to work properly. The plugin likely handles the cart quantities in a way that overrides your custom function.

You can solve this issue by adding some custom code that interacts directly with the Min/Max Quantities plugin. Here's an example of how you might do it:

```php
function custom_override_mmq_cart_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = null ) {
    // Fetching product
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

    // Fetching the min and max values from the product
    $minimum = $product->get_meta( '_wc_min_qty_product' );
    $maximum = $product->get_meta( '_wc_max_qty_product' );

    // Validation for the minimum value
    if ( $quantity < $minimum ) {
        $passed = false;
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( 'You must add a minimum of %s %s to your cart.' ), $minimum, get_the_title( $product_id ) ), 'error' );
    }

    // Validation for the maximum value
    if ( $quantity > $maximum ) {
        $passed = false;
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( 'You can add a maximum of %s %s to your cart.' ), $maximum, get_the_title( $product_id ) ), 'error' );
    }

    return $passed;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'custom_override_mmq_cart_validation', 10, 4 );
```

Please replace `_wc_min_qty_product` and `_wc_max_qty_product` with the actual meta keys the plugin uses to store the min/max quantities on the product. If you are not sure, you can check the plugin's code to find the correct meta keys.

This function adds a filter to the `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` hook, which is fired when WooCommerce is validating whether a product can be added to the cart. It checks whether the requested quantity of the product is within the minimum and maximum values you set for that product.

If the quantity is less than the minimum or greater than the maximum, it sets `$passed` to false and adds an error notice to the cart, preventing the product from being added.

Add this code to your theme's `functions.php` file, and ensure the Min/Max Quantities plugin is active.

Remember, modifying your theme's files directly can have unintended consequences.